# regular expression in jQuery for ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<span id="aaa_1_bbb">aaa</span>
<span id="aaa_2_bbb">aaa</span>
<span id="aaa_3_bbb">aaa</span>
<span id="aaa_4_bbb">aaa</span>
<span id="aaa_5_bbb">aaa</span>
<span id="aaa_6_bbb">aaa</span>
<span id="bbb_1_bbb">aaa</span>
<span id="ccc_1_bbb">aaa</span>
<span id="ddd_1_bbb">aaa</span>
<span id="aaa_1_xxx">aaa</span>

$('span[id="aaa_*_bbb"]').css('background-color', 'red');
```

how must i modify this jQuery? i would like that add css (background-color:red) only for aaa_*_bbb ID. * = numbers

**LIVE:** http://jsfiddle.net/HB3xf/2/

Comment: I've read your question four times, and I still don't know what you're asking.

Comment: @ColinFine: aaa_22222_bbb should be red

Comment: @Colin He wants a CSS selector that matches HTML ID by regular expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `.filter`

```
$('span').filter(function () { return /aaa_\d+_bbb/.test(this.id); }).css('background-color', 'red');
```

Answer (score 8):

As the HTML stands, you can use a combination of the [attribute starts with](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) and [attribute ends with](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/) selectors:

```
$('span[id^="aaa_"]').filter('[id$="_bbb"]').css('background-color', 'red');
```

**However**, if the HTML is under your control you should consider adding a `class` to these elements, or an `id` or `class` to their parent, so that you can select them in a more straightforward manner.

**[See it in action](http://jsfiddle.net/94QTR/)**.

Comment: The first selection gets aaa_* and the second one filters out those that only end in _bbb, therefore getting the result aaa_*_bbb @genesis

Comment: I like this one more than my implementation of filter :)

Comment: easy to forget the simplest solution

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like:

```
$('span').each(function() {

    var span_id = $(this).attr('id');
    if (span_id.substring(0, 3) == "aaa" && span_id.substring(span_id.length - 3, span_id.length) == "bbb") {
        $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
    }

});
```

It takes every span element and checks whether or not the first 3 characters are "aaa" and the last 3 are "bbb" and assigns the CSS if this is the case.

Comment: +1 thanks, this is ok, but i modified my example. i find other result.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use this: http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/regex-selector-for-jquery/

Answer (score 0):

The better option would be to set a specific class on those elements, like

```
<span id="aaa_1_bbb" class="aaabbb">aaa</span>
<span id="aaa_2_bbb" class="aaabbb">aaa</span>
<span id="aaa_3_bbb" class="aaabbb">aaa</span>
<span id="aaa_4_bbb" class="aaabbb">aaa</span>
<span id="aaa_5_bbb" class="aaabbb">aaa</span>
<span id="aaa_6_bbb" class="aaabbb">aaa</span>
<span id="bbb_1_bbb">aaa</span>
<span id="ccc_1_bbb">aaa</span>
<span id="ddd_1_bbb">aaa</span>
```

Then, you can just do `$('span.aaabbb').css('background-color', 'red');`